# Google App Engine deploys taking over 20 min

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine

I have a empty rails application I'm deploying on GAE. During each deploy process GAE downloads and installs ruby and re-installs all my Gems. I though after the first successful deploy it might cache some of this but that's not the case. Deploys are taking over 20min

Below is my app.yaml

```yaml
entrypoint: RAILS_ENV=develop bundle exec rails server --port $PORT
env: flex
runtime: ruby
resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 4
  disk_size_gb: 10
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

env_variables:
  RAILS_MASTER_KEY: ${RAILS_MASTER_KEY}
  RAILS_ENV: develop
  PROJECT_ID: homebase-develop

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: (redacted)
```

And I deploy it with `gcloud app deploy --stop-previous-version $GAE_CONFIG` where `GAE_CONFIG` points to the yaml above

Is there any way to speed up the deploy process? Most time is spent installing Ruby and Gems.

Comment: If you can use GAE Standard instead of GAE Flex, then deploys will be much faster (1-2 minutes).  There is no way to speed up GAE Flex deploys.

Answer (score 1):

Turns on GAE Flex is slow. Hey google, maybe work on this.